# Wrapper<MyComponent> or Wrapper<InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>>?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-test-utils

We are using TypeScript + [Vue Test Utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/) v1.0.0 and structuring the jest unit tests of our Vue components like this

```
import { shallowMount, Wrapper } from '@vue/test-utils';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.vue';

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let wrapper: Wrapper<MyComponent>; // solution A
  let wrapper: Wrapper<InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>>; // solution B

  describe('when X', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, /* ... */);
    });
    it('should do Y', () => {
      // assert some behavior on `wrapper`
    });
  });
});
```

I am more fond of the solution A because it's more readable, but it appears to produce the wrong type.

Indeed, the return type of `shallowMount(MyComponent, /* ... */)` is `Wrapper<CombinedVueInstance<MyComponent, object, object, object, Record<never, any>>>`, which is the same type that `Wrapper<InstanceType<typeof MyComponent>>` produces.

However, TypeScript does not report any error in either solution, which might indicates that `Wrapper<MyComponent>` is compatible with the "real" type.

So, my question is: will these types be always compatible? Can I always use the solution A?